# How to destroy all Processes from a Runtime at once?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, destroy

So for example:

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();` creates `Runtime rt`

`Process p1 = rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe");` creates `Process p1` on `Runtime rt`.

Then `p1.destroy();` will destroy `Process p1`.

My question is: If I have more than one `Process` (e.g. `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`), how do I destroy them all at once, instead of having to destroy them one by one?

Comment: Also consider `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Unplug is the solution.

Comment: @RomanC what do you mean by "unplug"?

Comment: Killing all processes at once, it would be nice idea.

Comment: @RomanC Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Keep a `List<Process>` of all your processes and destroy them in a loop.

```
List<Process> processes = ...

for(Process p : processes) {
    p.destroy();
}
```

Comment: So if I have all of my processes in a method called `Processes()`, could I create another method `destroyProcesses()` and put the loop there? Also, how would I reference the Processes from `destroyProcesses()`?

Comment: @user2506658 You would need to keep a reference to a [`List<Process>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of all your processes. Then you could access that list from a method, such as `destroyProcesses`, and do the work there. You might be interested in some basic [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to help you.

Comment: Also, I have never worked with lists before, and I can't find how to do it. Can you show me basically how to use `List<Process> processes = ...` for `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`?

Comment: @user2506658 Here's the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) tutorial. It will show you how to use a `List`.

Comment: Another thing, I haven't really worked with arrays before either... Could you give me a basic example?

Comment: @user2506658 And here's the [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) tutorial. Try [searching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/search.html) through the tutorials the next time you have a problem.

Comment: Ok, I am getting very lost and confused... If I give you the PasteBin link for my code, could you explain a little more on how to do this?